# React-native android appstate issue

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, react-native

```js
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.58.6"
```

In my app I have implemented a pin code protected lock screen. Whenever a user closes and then re-opens the app, this screen pops-up prompting for a pin code. I use `AppState` to check for checking the app's state:

```js
if (appState === "background" && nextAppState === "active") {
   // lock screen pops up
}
```

Apart from that, I have a screen where I ask for the location. The following popup shows up:

[image: enable location service]

So, today I have discovered that whenever this popup shows up, the app state changes to "background" and once I click "ok", the app state switches back to "active" and the lock screen shows up. This is very inconvenient and harms the UX.

Is there any way to prevent such behavior?

Comment: any solution for this issue?

Comment: @AnilkumariOSReactNative unfortunately, no

Comment: Then how you handled that situation?

Comment: This is my query, Any suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832423/appstate-keep-on-getting-change-in-react-native-in-android

Comment: @ AnilkumariOSReactNative i didn't, i left it all as it is.

Comment: This solution worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62589552/1743772