# Appstate keep on getting change in React native in Android

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation, location, addeventlistener

I am working on React native project and there I am taking location permissions. Also I have to track location permissions always like if user has given permission access after install the application and then after sometime user goes to the app settings in device settings and disable/revoked the permissions. Again once app comes from background to foreground, I have to check permission based on that, Needs to show the messages.

So that, I am using Appstate. But, In Android strangely, After installed the application, If user denied the permission with "Dont show again" checkbox, Then Appstate getting keep on changing with **background** and **active** always.
It is keep on loop.

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
    Geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
  }

  handleAppStateChange = async nextAppState => {
    const {appState} = this.state;
    console.log('nextAppState -->', nextAppState);
    console.log('appState -->', appState);
    if (appState === 'active') {
      // do this
      this.showLoader();
      await this.requestAndroidLocationPermission();
    } else if (appState === 'background') {
      // do that
    } else if (appState === 'inactive') {
      // do that other thing
    }
   
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  };

requestAndroidLocationPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {},
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        this.getLatitudeLongitude();
      } else if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.NEVER_ASK_AGAIN) {
        this.hideLoader();
        this.setState({
          errorMessage: 'Location permission is denied',
          isLoading: false,
        });
      } else {
        this.hideLoader();
        this.requestAndroidLocationPermission();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };
```

It is keep on printing (loop) after **denied permission with Don't show again**

```
appState --> active
nextAppState --> background
appState --> active
nextAppState --> background
appState --> active
nextAppState --> background
appState --> active
```

It goes on and never stops.

How to handle this? Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of React Native are you using?  The latest documentation states below.  [https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate#change]

"Add a handler to AppState changes by listening to the change event type and providing the handler

TODO: now that AppState is a subclass of NativeEventEmitter, we could deprecate addEventListener and removeEventListener and use addListener and listener.remove() directly. That will be a breaking change though, as both the method and event names are different (addListener events are currently required to be globally unique)."

Comment: HI there, have you solved your problem, I am getting the same issue and not sure whats the problem!!!

Comment: @Yasir, Not I did not solved

Comment: I am getting the same issue anyone solved this?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. Do not use AppState. Is faulty.

the problem lies within RN's definition of "background". react-native uses android's activity (the holder of the UI thread and where your UI lives) onPause callback as the trigger for sending the "background" signal. But, onPause is called everytime SOMETHING comes in front of your activity's view hierachy, like Dialogs (like the permission box), other activities (like a file picker), etc; for android react-native, "background" means "shadowed by a foreign UI element/android task" rather than "paused and sent to background to do something else", thus causing the loops you see. The shortest solution is to override onPause in your ReactActivity, and add control conditions to make sure super.onPause is only called when you are actually going to background, like checking your task stack, or if the permission dialog is being called, so you avoid this kind of loop/faulty call. A second option would be to provide your own app lifecycle event instead, with clear triggering conditions.

Comment: Nice! Can you please give me some idea how to fix it? How to provide own app lifecycle event?

Comment: You need to check your app's task pile. Usually you are going to have a single activity on top. If your activity is hidden by another, but from within your app, or called by your app, you'll have two processes in your task pile. So you know you are not in background. You can also spy if you have any DialogFragments active, which also hide the app. Based on those metrics, you need to send an event through DeviceEventEmitter indicating the actual state of the app. This varies a bit depending on your app's design.

Comment: @FcoP. any document or reference link will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Use "focus" in Android and "change" in iOS.

I have a custom hook like this:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { AppState, Platform } from 'react-native';

const focusEvent = Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'focus' : 'change';

const useLocationListener = () => {


  useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener(focusEvent, handleAppStateChange);

    getLocationAsync();
    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener(focusEvent, handleAppStateChange);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState: string) => {
    if (nextAppState === 'active') {
      getLocationAsync();
    }
  };

  const getLocationAsync = async () => {
    const { canAskAgain, status } = await Permissions.getAsync(
      Permissions.LOCATION
    );

    if (canAskAgain) {
      const response = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
       // handle location 
    } 
       // handle location with "status"
    
  };
};

export default useLocationListener;
```

Comment: Hey man, works. However, in your example ios returns "change" and android returns "focus" (you mixed them up ;))

Comment: works for me too, but the `focus` event doesn't send an app state so `getLocationAsync` will never get triggered in this example. I think you would need a Platform check in here as well `if (Platform.OS === 'android' || nextAppState === 'active')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a flag that check whether app should handle background or it's just a permission call.

```
const shouldHandleBackground = useRef(true)

const handler = (state) => { 
    if (state === 'active' && shouldHandleBackground.current) { 
        doStuff() 
    }
}

// when calling for permisson make the flag false

shouldHandleBackground.current = false
await Android.permission.LocationPermission()
shouldHandleBackground.current = true
```

and after permission request you can make flag true

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @FcoP. you need to have your own app lifecycle event.
It can be done by updating your MainActivity.java file

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;

@Override
  public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      ReactContext reactContext = getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();
      WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
      params.putString("event", "active");

      // when app starts reactContext will be null initially until bridge between Native and React Native is established
      if(reactContext != null) {
          getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext()
              .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
              .emit("ActivityStateChange", params);
      }
  }
  @Override
  public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      ReactContext reactContext = getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();
      WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
      params.putString("event", "inactive");

      if(reactContext != null) {
          getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext()
                  .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                  .emit("ActivityStateChange", params);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
      super.onStop();
      ReactContext reactContext = getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();
      WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
      params.putString("event", "background");

      if(reactContext != null) {
          getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext()
                  .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                  .emit("ActivityStateChange", params);
      }
  }


Then in your component 

import { NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules } from 'react-native';

 const appStateEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter();
      const subscription = appStateEmitter.addListener(
        'ActivityStateChange',
        (e) => {
          console.log(e.event);          
        }
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I made my code work via @Kushagra Agarwal's answer

That's my fullcode of MainActivity.java

```
package [yourpackage];

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;

import expo.modules.ReactActivityDelegateWrapper;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Set the theme to AppTheme BEFORE onCreate to support 
    // coloring the background, status bar, and navigation bar.
    // This is required for expo-splash-screen.
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(null);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
   * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "main";
  }

  /**
   * Returns the instance of the {@link ReactActivityDelegate}. Here we use a util class {@link
   * DefaultReactActivityDelegate} which allows you to easily enable Fabric and Concurrent React
   * (aka React 18) with two boolean flags.
   */
  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegateWrapper(this, BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED, new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
        this,
        getMainComponentName(),
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled(), // fabricEnabled
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable Concurrent React (i.e. React 18).
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getConcurrentReactEnabled() // concurrentRootEnabled
        ));
  }

  /**
   * Align the back button behavior with Android S
   * where moving root activities to background instead of finishing activities.
   * @see <a href="https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onBackPressed()">onBackPressed</a>
   */
  @Override
  public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
      if (!moveTaskToBack(false)) {
        // For non-root activities, use the default implementation to finish them.
        super.invokeDefaultOnBackPressed();
      }
      return;
    }

    // Use the default back button implementation on Android S
    // because it's doing more than {@link Activity#moveTaskToBack} in fact.
    super.invokeDefaultOnBackPressed();
  }


  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/77136574/2317862
  // Override the ReactActivity class, attach listener by ourself
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ReactContext reactContext = getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();
    WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
    params.putString("event", "active");

    // when app starts reactContext will be null initially until bridge between Native and React Native is established
    if(reactContext != null) {
      reactContext
        .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
        .emit("ActivityStateChange", params);
    }
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ReactContext reactContext = getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();
    WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
    params.putString("event", "inactive");

    if(reactContext != null) {
      reactContext
        .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
        .emit("ActivityStateChange", params);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ReactContext reactContext = getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();
    WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
    params.putString("event", "background");

    if(reactContext != null) {
      reactContext
        .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
        .emit("ActivityStateChange", params);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Upvote is always helpful

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, Android devices go to background when requesting permission as opposed to iOS devices, so that's why the loop happens.
With the help of this comment [request permission always returns denied](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/16701#issuecomment-1270111253) I was able to solve the infinite loop, here is my code, I used React hooks though, hope it helps someone:

```
const [permissionResponse, setPermissionResponse] = useState<Location.LocationPermissionResponse>();
const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);

    useEffect(() => {
        requestPermissionAndExecute(passMethodToBeExecuted);
        const appStateSubscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);

        return () => {
            appStateSubscription.remove();
        }
    }, []);

    const requestPermissionAndExecute = async (callback: () => void) => {
        const permissionResponse = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        setPermissionResponse(permissionResponse);
        if (permissionResponse.granted) {
            callback();
        }
    }

    const handleAppStateChange = async (nextAppState: AppStateStatus) => {
        if (nextAppState === appState.current) return;

        const isTransitioningToForeground = appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active';

        if (isTransitioningToForeground) {
            await requestPermissionAndExecute(passMethodToBeExecuted);
        } else {
            // App went to background
        }

        appState.current = nextAppState;
    }
```

The main problem for me was that I wasn't checking for this conditional
`appState.current.match(/inactive|background/)`, but was doing only this `nextAppState === 'active'`

Also I had to do await when calling requestPermissionAndExecute(passMethodToBeExecuted) inside handleAppStateChange method.

That fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

**If you want only to get nextAppState === 'active' on Android**

```
    export const useAppState = () => {
    const [appState, setAppState] = useState(AppState.currentState);
    const [timestamp, setTimestamp] = useState<number | null>(null);
    const backgroundTimestamp = useRef<number | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (
            Platform.OS === 'android' &&
            timestamp &&
            !!backgroundTimestamp?.current
        ) {
            const diff = timestamp - backgroundTimestamp?.current;
            if (diff > 1000) {
                setAppState('background');
            }
            backgroundTimestamp.current = null;
            setTimestamp(null);
        }
    }, [timestamp]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android' && appState === 'background') {
            setAppState('active');
        }
    }, [appState]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const subscription: any = AppState.addEventListener(
            'change',
            nextAppState => {
                if (
                    nextAppState === 'background' &&
                    Platform.OS === 'android'
                ) {
                    backgroundTimestamp.current = new Date().valueOf();
                } else {
                    setAppState(nextAppState);
                    if (
                        Platform.OS === 'android' &&
                        nextAppState === 'active' &&
                        !!backgroundTimestamp.current
                    ) {
                        setTimestamp(new Date().valueOf());
                    }
                }
            },
        );
        return () => {
            subscription?.remove();
        };
    }, []);

    return appState;
};
```